# JavaScript Object Grouping by Property and pushing to new object

Tags: javascript, arrays, handlebars.js, javascript-objects

I need help with reading an object, grouping by name and counting each occurrence.

I then need to push the results into another object which i can iterate with handlebars.

Here's my sample object:

```
var names = [ 
{ "name": "Person A" },
{ "name": "Person B" },
{ "name": "Person C" },
{ "name": "Person D" },
{ "name": "Person B" },
{ "name": "Person C" },
{ "name": "Person B" }
];
```

I have found some code which will loop through it and tally up the names:

```
        for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {

            if(!count[names[i].name]){
                count[names[i].name] = 0;                    
            }
            count[names[i].name]++;
        }
```

Which gives me the following:

[image]

I need to push these results into a new objects for handlebars to read.  So i need the data to be in this format:

[image]

This is what i've managed so far, i'm struggling to push the data into my response objects as new items.  I don't know how to retrieve the name and total from the count object.

```
// Set up the data to be returned
var names = [ 
{ "name": "Person A" },
{ "name": "Person B" },
{ "name": "Person C" },
{ "name": "Person D" },
{ "name": "Person B" },
{ "name": "Person C" },
{ "name": "Person B" }
];
var count = {};
var response = { items:[] };



        for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {

            if(!count[names[i].name]){
                count[names[i].name] = 0;                    
            }
            count[names[i].name]++;
        }             


// Loop through the count object and populate response items
for(var key in count) {

    response.items.push({
            // How do i put the name and total here?
            "name": "Person A",
            "total": 12345
    });
}


console.log(count);
console.log(response);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it what you expected?

```
for (var key in count) {
    response.items.push({
        "name": key,
        "total": count[key]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:
Use `forin` loop like below.

```js
var names = [{
    "name": "Person A"
  },
  {
    "name": "Person B"
  },
  {
    "name": "Person C"
  },
  {
    "name": "Person D"
  },
  {
    "name": "Person B"
  },
  {
    "name": "Person C"
  },
  {
    "name": "Person B"
  }
];

var count = {};
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {

  if (!count[names[i].name]) {
    count[names[i].name] = 0;
  }
  count[names[i].name]++;
}

var res = [];
for(var i in count) {
  if(count.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    res.push({name:i, total:count[i]});
  }
}
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const names = [ 
{ "name": "Person A" },
{ "name": "Person B" },
{ "name": "Person C" },
{ "name": "Person D" },
{ "name": "Person B" },
{ "name": "Person C" },
{ "name": "Person B" }
]

const count = names.reduce((count, item) => (
  count[item.name]
  ? count[item.name]++
  : count[item.name] = 1
  , count)
, {})

const result = Array.from(Object.keys(count), (key) => ({ name: key, total: count[key] }))

console.log(result)
```